# What is the keyboard shortcut to inspect an element using Firefox?

Tags: firefox, web-inspector

In Chrome you can press `Command`+`Option`+`c` to switch directly into element inspection mode. What's the equivilent keyboard shortcut in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

F12 opens it for me in Chrome and in Firefox

Comment: Also, F12 only seems to open the dev tools in Firefox, but does not activate selection mode.

Comment: On a Mac F12 only works in Firefox, not Chrome. And it isn't a keyboard shortcut to inspect an element. It only opens the dev tools panel.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Firefox Developer Tools Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts#Page_Inspector)

- **Windows & Linux**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
- **Mac**: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Also, these will open and close the dev tools:

- **Windows & Linux**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
- **Mac**: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>